# OpenSqlFileStream - Access is denied - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008, filestream, windows-authentication

Using filestream to upload documents into a SQL Server 2008 database. Database is on one server, and trying to upload a file from a different server via services.

Configurations

1. MSDTC enabled for both - Inbound, outbound...everything.
2. Connection is using Windows Authentication with Integrated Security=True in connection string.
3. Services which is trying to connect to DB is running on a domain account which has windows authentication on DB and is admin on DB.
4. Filestream is enabled in the database
5. Data folder of SQL Server has been provided full access to the domain user.
6. Data folder of SQL Server is not read only.
7. Windows firewall is disbaled - Private, Public everything.

But still we get the following error

> Access is denied - OpenSqlFileStream

Comment: You will need to **show us some code** .....

Comment: I am missing some configuration settings, because we are setting completely new environment of an existing working code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you may tried below link. Another option I may suggest is CLR Function.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: As i have commented in the above question, we are missing some configuration settings, because we are setting completely new environment of an existing working code. And we have done what you have shared in the link.